# Alternative to Reco4j for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Are there any recommendation engines or ML Libraries like Mahout, Jubatus etc which can be integrated with the neo4j. [Reco4j](http://www.neotechnology.com/using-neo4j-and-reco4j-for-graph-based-recommendations/) was one where one can integrate the clustering and recommendation libraries(like collaborative figuring) but its currently not working and doesn't seem to be live in near future. Any other engines which can be used with Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphAware Reco` is a simple framework to build a general recommendation engine. It also has a few classes that are built directly for `Neo4j`, using Node and Relationship.

By the way, the project works for versions of Neo4j greater than 2.1.5, but you can use the same structure even for previous versions.

Take a look at

- [github project](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-reco)
- [A simple video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/118837191)
- [GraphAware products](http://graphaware.com/products/)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a recommendation engine solely with Neo4j. For an example look at [Nicole's graphgist](http://gist.neo4j.org/?8173017).

Comment: Thanks Stefan. But how can one implement [collaborative figuring](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Collaborative_filtering.gif) using neo4j that is my primary concern.

Comment: Also If there are 10^6 persons, then creating a similarity link between each of them does not seem worth. As many of them will be totally far apart. In such cases clustering might be a solution..That is to only do calculation on a particular cluster than on a complete graph at any instant.